# How to create a dependency / library with inheritance of an existing dependency(Google AdMob) and use it through my dependency?

Tags: android, maven, compilation, android-gradle-plugin

**I am creating this library and using Google AdMob in it. After uploading it to JFrog Bintray I recieved an gradle link. I tried to use that to compile but I got an error of Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0**

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

```
group = 'Package-Name'
version = 'Version-number'

bintray {
    user = "user-name"
    key = "API-Key"

    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'name'

        licenses = [required-license]
    }
    configurations = ['archives']
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classifier 'sources'
    }

    task generateJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath()
                .join(File.pathSeparator))
    }

    task generateJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
        from generateJavadocs.destinationDir
        classifier 'javadoc'
    }
    artifacts {
        archives generateJavadocsJar
        archives generateSourcesJar
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-

core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-`annotations'`
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

How can I solve this issue?
Please do help.
Thank you in advance.